# Show modal window on click of tab close

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am using react hook `useBeforeunload` to detect tab close event and want to display a modal window but I am stuck with below code. On click of close icon(X), it's not showing modal window which I am setting to true with setVisible and simply exiting the tab.

```
import { useBeforeunload } from 'react-beforeunload';

 const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);

 const showModalWindow = (e) => {
  setVisible(true);
 }

useBeforeunload((e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    showModalWindow();
  });
```

Any suggestions to make this work will be really helpful. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: the package uses beforeunload event of the window which only popup a dialog with a message and the only options are leave the page and cancel. Doing setState inside will not work maybe for some security reason. [see this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event)

Answer (score 0):

First problem, `useBeforeUnload` is expecting you to return a string in your handler function.

Second problem, the `usebeforeunload` eventListener (which this package is using) will in most modern browsers not display a modal that you are trying to render. What happens instead is that the browsers will show a native dialogue asking you if you are sure you want to leave the page.

So if you make your event handler return a `string`, you should probably see the native dialogue if you try to close the tab.

You can find more info here:

https://github.com/jacobbuck/react-beforeunload

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event

Comment: Thanks but this does not solve the problem I am facing. I want to show a modal window on click of tab close icon.

Comment: @JyotiDuhan As far as I know, there is now way in most modern browsers to show a custom modal when the user tries to close the tab. If you would look at the link to the Mozilla docs that I provided, you'd see that only Internet Explorer allows any custom messages or custom execution of code. So unless your users are all on IE or old versions of other browsers, I don't think you will be able to show a custom modal when the window/tab is closed. Unfortunately, I believe the answer to your question is that you can't do what you are trying to do.

Comment: yes, you are right. Instead I used onmouseleave event when user leaves the web view and got the result what I wanted.